# minitest, test::unit, and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit, minitest

I read somewhere that 'minitest' is the "new test::unit for ruby 1.9.2+".

But ruby 1.9.3 seems to include *both* [test::unit](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit.html) *and* [minitest](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest.html), is that true?

In the default rails testing, as outlined in the [Rails testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)....  things like `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, `ActionController::TestCase`, are these using `Test::Unit` or `Minitest`?

In the rails guide, it shows examples with tests defined like this:

```
test "should show post" do
  get :show, :id => @post.id
  assert_response :success
end
```

That syntax, `test string`, as opposed to defining methods with names like `test_something` --  isn't mentioned in the docs for *either* `Test::Unit` or Minitest.  Where's that coming from?  Is Rails adding it, or is it actually a part of... whatever testing lib rails is using?

PS: Please don't tell me "just use rspec". I know about rspec. I am trying to explore the stdlib alternatives, in the context of rails.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a `Test::Unit` "compatibility" module that comes with Minitest, so that you can (presumably) use your existing Test::Unit tests as-is.  This is probably the `Test::Unit` module you are seeing.

As of rails 3.2.3, generator-created tests include `rails/test_help` which includes `test/unit`.

The `test "something" do` syntax is a rails extension.  It's [defined](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Declarative.html) in `ActiveSupport::Testing::Declarative`, which is `require`'d by `rails/test_help`.

Comment: The "compatiblity" mode is a joke - they don't bother matching up the assert* function naming conventions and it just goes downhill from there.

Answer (score 5):

This is perhaps a bit of a tangential response, but as to your rspec comment... You might want to take a look at `minitest/spec` which provides spec flavor syntax in stdlib in 1.9.x.

http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Spec.html